# Gboard: Is there anyway to switch language by swiping spacebar?

Tags: languages, gboard

I have two languages on Gboard and when I want to switch between them, I have to press the globe button. Is there anyway to switch language by swiping spacebar?
I've seen this feature on Samsung Keyboard and I was wondering if it's available on the new Gboard.

Comment: Simply use SwiftKey..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no as such settings that enables you the Language switch on the basis of swiping Spacebar.

But there are two options you can set in the settings.

**1. Enables the Switch Language Key:-** It enables you with the same features like swipe to change the language, on Clicking on this Globe Switch key your language will get automatically switched based on their preferences in the `Settings`.
if you have to do more with the language then this is the best option.

**2. By clicking on Spacebar:-**
if you have disabled the Language Switch in `Settings`. then you can get the language Popup by clicking on the `Spacebar`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Once you set up the Gboard, un your input settings , select Gboard as your preferred keyboard and save. Go in messages or WhatsApp or browser wherever you need to type and make your Gboard appear. Long press the comma at the left of the space bar,you'll have the option to get into settings of Gboard, where it proposes you to select the language. Set off "use system language" and select as many languages desired. You'll be then good to go and will be able to switch between selected languages through long press on space bar.

Answer (score -1):

Swiping the spacebar is available in Hacker's keyboard.